# Save attachment from mails sent to a shared box(Exchange Online) in SharePoint 2016 library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I have a requirement where the user wants to store all the attachments attached in a mail sent to a specific mailbox to be stored in a sharepoint 2016 library.

Now I know that we can use flow to save it in sharepoint online library but not sure how to implement the same in onprem

Note: If you are going to suggest to first save it in online library and them copy it to on prem please tell the how to copy the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is a method to save the SharePoint Online or Exchange Online file in SharePoint on-premise environment directly.

I suggest you copy the files from the SharePoint Online library to local and copy them to SharePoint 2016 library using file explorer.